# Registering Variables and Functions Declarations in Java Script

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, global, interpretation

I was watching a video on javascript scopes which said that just before browser interprets java script code, it actually involves a quick compilation step(well not exactly 'compilation' so to speak since it does not involve making an intermediary file) which registers variable and function declaration in their respective scope.
So if i write:

```
var a = 3;
function foo(){
var c = 2;
}
```

Before evaluating above expression which means ignoring R.H.S. part, variable 'a' and function 'foo' will be registered in global scope and inside the scope of 'foo', variable 'c' will be registered.
After this compilation step, expressions will be evaluated for their values.

But what happens when we write:

```
var a = function(){
var c;
}
```

Will the compilation step just register variable 'a' in global scope and skip function declaration and variable 'c' declaration since compilation step is supposed to skip the R.H.S. part and evaluating expressions comes in interpreter part?

Comment: The a is still a global and the function is anonymous function expression and will be evaluated where it is positioned, it doesn't get hoisted like a named/declared function and c is still registered as local to the function's scope.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I figured it out later. It is Hoisting. Hoisting only works for variables and function declaration and not function expression.
Turns out that the only time functions in function expression and their local variables gets registered is when the java script interpreter runs(after compilation) as the compilation step would not bother about them since they are on the R.H.S part.                                                                                    This makes sure that in case of function expression, we call it only after its assignment and the interpreter takes care of the function being registered in global scope, assigning it to the L.H.S. variable and declaration of its local variable (var bar;):

```js
var foo = function() {
  console.log(bar);
  var bar = 5;
};
foo();
```

This function object is created only when interpreter reaches this line:

```
var foo = function abc() {
```

Had this been a case of function declaration, something like this:

```js
foo();

function foo() {
  console.log(bar);
  var bar = 5;
}
```

Hoisting would have made sure that at the compilation step that it registers function 'foo' and declares variable 'bar' inside its scope.

Nonetheless, both programs will give same output - 'undeifned'.